# benchmarking javascript on a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, benchmarking

I have a web page with about 1000 lines of javascript in it. I'm experiencing some troubles with javascript behavior and i'm pretty sure this has to do with the large amount of javascript insctructions in this view (mos of them are jQuery). For example, some javascript events or triggers are delayed for few seconds. Or I have to click 2 or 3 times on a button to close a jquery dialog box.

I will start optimize these 1000 lines of javascript, and I would like to see how efficient are my optimizations. How can I benchmark the javascript usage of the page before and after optimizations ? Do browser consoles (or firebug) have such tools ? Or should I install something more ?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer have profiling tools built into "Developer Tools" - F12 on all of them.

Comment: FWIW, 1000 lines isn't a large amount of javascript instructions... The sheer number of lines isn't going to be causing a problem - but yes, depending on what they're doing...!  Not sure on the others, but the Chrome dev tools are [very well documented](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), including a section on [profiling performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/profile-performance/index?hl=en).